# Parse multiple values from a bytes array

Tags: solidity

Here is my `bytes` array: `[28,2,1994]`

Now, I want to create a function that parses each value and assigns it to its own `uint256` variable.

Here is an example:

`uint256 day = 28;`

`uint256 month = 2;`

`uint256 year = 1994;`

That said, I have a function that converts an entire `bytes` array to a `uint256`:

```
 function bytesToUint(bytes memory data) private pure returns (uint256) {
        require(data.length <= 32, "Invalid data length");
        uint256 result = 0;
        for (uint256 index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            result = result << 8;
            result += uint8(data[index]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I need this function to return 3 separate values that I can use in a separate function.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Maybe you could explain the format of your bytes array a bit more. How are you inputting bytes memory into the function? 1994 is greater than 2^8 and thus doesn't fit into a uint8 size.